# Generate excel chart from smart marker aspose

Tags: excel, charts, aspose

I have an excel template with following two columns period and points, trend.period and trend.points are aspose smart marker that represent the data.

```
Period          Points
&=trend.period  &=trend.points
```

The table generated is below.

```
Period  Points
4Q'14   27
1Q'15   0
2Q'15   0
3Q'15   0
4Q'15   200
```

It's easy to generate column chart for table 2, how to generate the same chart for table 1 with smart marker?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may accomplish the task using Aspose.Cells' Smart Markers feature. All you need to do is create Named ranges based on your Smart Markers inserted into the cells. I have written a sample code using Aspose.Cells APIs for your requirements. Please refer to it and you may add/update the code segment accordingly for your needs.

e.g

Sample code:

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable("Trend");
        dt.Columns.Add("Period", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Points", typeof(int));

        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = "4Q'14";
        row[1] = 27;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = "1Q'15";
        row[1] = 0;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = "2Q'15";
        row[1] = 0;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = "3Q'15";
        row[1] = 0;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = "4Q'15";
        row[1] = 200;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);


        WorkbookDesigner wd = new WorkbookDesigner();

        //Create a designer workbook
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
        Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
        worksheet.Cells["A1"].PutValue("Period");
        worksheet.Cells["A2"].PutValue("&=Trend.Period");

        worksheet.Cells["B1"].PutValue("Points");
        worksheet.Cells["B2"].PutValue("&=Trend.Points");

        Range range1 = worksheet.Cells.CreateRange("A2:A2");
        range1.Name = "RANGE1";
        Range range2 = worksheet.Cells.CreateRange("B2:B2");
        range2.Name = "RANGE2";

        wd.Workbook = workbook;

        wd.SetDataSource(dt);
        wd.Process();

        //Create chart
        int chartIndex = worksheet.Charts.Add(ChartType.Column, 5, 2, 29, 10);
        Chart chart = worksheet.Charts[chartIndex];

        //Obtain the updated ranges after processing smart markers
        var r1 = workbook.Worksheets.GetRangeByName("RANGE1");
        var r2 = workbook.Worksheets.GetRangeByName("RANGE2");

        MessageBox.Show(r2.RefersTo);
        //Add the nseries collection to a chart 
        chart.NSeries.Add(r2.RefersTo, true);
        //Get or set the range of category axis values
        chart.NSeries.CategoryData = r1.RefersTo;
        chart.NSeries.IsColorVaried = true;


        wd.Workbook.Save("e:\\test2\\out1chart1.xlsx");
```

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Hi Amjad, a follow up question, can we hide this table if it doesn't have data? This table belongs to a big spreadsheet, and the sheet contains more than 20 tables like this and my client wants to hide these empty tables. Is it doable? As far as I know, I can put each tables in a separate sheet, but that may generate more than 10 sheets in some case.

Comment: Do you mean to say to hide Smart Markers e.g "&=Trend.Period" and "&=Trend.Points" in the cells? Well, if there is no record in the underlying table, the Smart Markers would be removed from those cells (A2 and B2). And, if you need not to create the chart if there is no record in the data table, you may simply check (in your code) using DataTable.Rows.Count attribute if a table is empty, so you should not create the chart via Aspose.Cells APIs.

Comment: I mean for example, if there are 15 tables in my sheet, if one table doesn't have data, can we hide it? The client says it's annoying to see those empty tables because on the webpage we are dynamically hiding those tables according to each user's setting.

Comment: Well, you may hide relevant rows/cols in the sheet using Aspose.Cells APIs if it helps a bit, see the topic (http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Hiding+and+Showing+Rows+and+Columns) for your reference. Also, there is no such feature available in Smart Markers to auto-hide those empty tables/data when imported, so you got to do it manually via Aspose.Cells APIs to accomplish the task.